# Why texture painting without color?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

i am texture painting my model and i can't figure out this: i am trying to paint with this "pois texture" i have made (.png with alpha) but, as you can see in ther picture, it appear without its color on the mesh. (instead of purple)

My first time using Blender texture painting tools so i am sorry if this will result a very basic question.
[image]

Comment: Your color is set to dark green

Comment: YEP! *****!!! Didnt know the color was influencing the texture. I had the feeling was something basic and "simple"! Thanks so much Denis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using a brush texture in paint mode the value of the texture is mixed with the brush color.
To paint with the original color of the texture set the brush color to pure white.